# Color Coding Legend

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint Calendar in which the various events in the calendar are color coded. How can I add a color coding lengend above the calendar? The purpose of the legend is to associate the colors to the event categories.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have a custom calendar web part? Why not just put a content editor web part and design the content as you wish?

Comment: Vladi, I added a new content web editor and was able to insert my color legend above the calendar.
Thanks!!!!!